# SAPUI5 Check model has set to the view

Tags: sapui5

How can we check whether a model is set a particular view in SAPUI5.

usually we will set model through this.getView.setModel();

Does UI5 view has any property to check whether it has any model binded to it ? it doesn't have hasModel that returns a true or false.

Thanks,
Prasad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call method **getModel** and if it returns undefined the specific model is not set. The view has a method **hasModel** but this just checks if at least one model is set to the view or it's parents.